# Newbie on "Script-Generate"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie to Ruby on Rails and I am trying to learn it.

At the moment, I am using [ruby tutorial](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/ruby/archive/rails.html?page=2) that is about 5 years old.

I am stuck on the 2nd page of the tutorial where I am generating a script or the controller in the command window.

```
C:\rails> ruby script\generate controller MyTest 
ruby: No such file or directory script/generate (LoadError)
```

What are my alternative to generating the script? And if possible, can someone show me a tutorial that isn't so outdated?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but that could be a problem with ruby on windows, what version of ruby are you running? Type `ruby -v` in the console.

Another reason could be that you are probably not in a rails application directory. You have to create a rails application by creating a directory, and then doing `rails thedirectory/` in the console, which will initialize all of the rails files for you. Once done, you `cd` into the directory and should be able to run the `script/generate` script.

Also, this is by no means a definitive source, but the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) site is pretty good.

Comment: ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out. I just google for a tutorial and it showed me that one and I thought this one would do.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're not in the right folder.  If you're following the tutorial you linked, you need to 'cd cookbook' from the c:\rails folder.

Comment: Doh! Didn't think I had to be in the directory of the Cookbook. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As for a tutorial, looked at [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have not, and I will